# Include Dependencies automatically with Karma

Tags: karma-runner

I am working on a large project and they use a CDN for various javascript libs and files (there's about 50 of them)

Do I need to include all dependencies in the karma configuration file (karma.conf.js)?

If so, is there any easier way than defining each file? I realize that when they are local I can use a global "*".

For example,

```
files: [
   'https://d...s.cloudfront.net/js/*.js'
]
```

Comment: you can use `/**/*.js` for a local folder (and subfolders), but for a CDN... :/